# How to find the closed form of a power series

Tags: calculus

What is the closed form of this power series?
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\dfrac{x^n}{n}$$
I notice that it looks pretty similar to the Maclaurin series of $e^x$ but I don't know (or probably forgot) how to systemically find the series's closed form.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: look at $ln(x)$

Comment: *Hint*: What do you get when you (term-by-term) differentiate the series?

Comment: Note that the series for $\mathrm{e}^x$ has $n!$, not $n$ in the denominators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $|x|<1$ the function $f(x) = \sum_{n\ge 1} (-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n}$ is well defined, has derivatives of all orders, and those derivatives have a power series representation corresponding to a term-by-term differentiation of $f(x)$. Hence, for $|x|<1$, we have that
$$
f'(x)= \sum_{n \ge 1} (-1)^{n+1} x^{n-1} = \sum_{n \ge 0} (- x)^n = \frac{1}{x+1}.
$$

So, noting that $f(0)=0$,

$$
f(x) = \int_0^x \frac{dt}{1+t} = \log(1+x).
$$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not $e^x$.

Let $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\dfrac{x^n}{n}s$ for $|x|<1$ ( In other $x$ series is divergent by Cauchy criteria)

Let's differentiate it piece by piece due series is covergent
$ \displaystyle f'(x)  = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \cdot x^{n-1} $
This is geometric series wich you can sum up and integrate it back